# How to backp ZFS BIOS, and UEFI, partitions?

Tags: uefi, backup, bios, zfs, snapshot

I have a working Ubuntu 22.04 installation on a RAIDed encrypted ZFS file system. The procedure I followed can be downloaded from:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/2w8mdb96tbzslub/Ubuntu_22.04_Root_on_ZFS_Encryption.odt/file
This procedure is a customized version of rlaager's at:
https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html

The snapshot procedure I did is:

```
# Snapshot the Pools

zfs snapshot bpool/BOOT@snap_boot    
zfs snapshot rpool/ROOT@snap_root    
zfs snapshot rpool/USERDATA@snap_userdata    
zfs snapshot hpool/HOME@snap_home

# Verify the snapshots are created:

zfs list -t snapshot | grep  "@snap"
```

My concern now is about how to backup the UEFI, and BIOS, partitions. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by UEFI and BIOS partitions and why would you want to snapshot them?

Comment: I will just say I am about to do something risky that I do not know if it will have a damaging effect on those two partitions.